# Why is the default zram value is 1/4 of ram? Why not high values?

Tags: swap

I noticed the usually value of zram is 1/4 of total ram.
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM

Why is bad use like 3/4 or total of ram?

Answer (score 3):

From that very page is a section [Why not a bigger zram device?](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM#Why_not_a_bigger_zram_device.3F)

> #### Why not a bigger zram device?
>
> The main idea of being conservative is to address concerns about upgrades. It's possible some workloads will have less compressible data. Hence, not going with /dev/zram0 sized to 100% of RAM at this time. Even a /dev/zram0 of 200% RAM is not unreasonable *if* the compression ratio is at least 2:1. However, it's possible a system can get "stuck" in a kind of swap thrashing similar to conventional swap-on-drive, except it's CPU and memory bound, rather than IO bound. Feature owner thinks it's better to just oom, instead of getting overly aggressive with the zram device size.
>
> Conversely it's possible to be too conservative with the size, and result in more instances of OOM kill. If applying the feature to upgrades is rejected, it's probably reasonable to increase the cap to ~8GiB. Of course more feedback and testing is needed, and it will be taken into consideration.
>
> Note that the kernel zram doc says an excessively sized zram device does come with overhead. Users's can increase the size easily post-install, a capability they don't easily have with swap-on-drive. The goal for Fedora 33 is a default that's useful and safe for the vast majority of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 34 proposed zram increase to factor 1.0 RAM https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Scale_ZRAM_to_full_memory_size